# I'm trying to append a range of numbers onto a string in Python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, concatenation

The desired outcome I'm try to achieve is similar to this:

```
192.168.1.70    
192.168.1.71    
192.168.1.72    
192.168.1.73    
etc...
```

This is what I came up with but it isn't producing the desired outcome:

```
IP = "192.168.1."

for n in range(70,91):

    IP += str(n) + "\n"

print(IP)
```

Instead it prints something like this:

```
192.168.1.70    
71    
72    
73    
etc...
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm totally lost.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to think through the problem logically. For example, what do you expect `IP` to be equal to at the beginning of the first iteration? At the end of the first iteration? At the beginning of the second iteration? etc. Now, *test* your expectations. Are they met? If not, do you see why? Please try to find the problem yourself first and, failing that, *ask a question* - "any help would be much appreciated" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
[f"192.168.1.{i}" for i in range(70, 91)]
```

Output:

```
['192.168.1.70',
 '192.168.1.71',
 '192.168.1.72',
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to not use the same variable. Instead:

```
IP = "192.168.1."
IPout =""

for n in range(70,91):    
    IPout += IP + str(n) + "\n"

print(IPout)
```

Essentially you want to concatenate to your `IPout` variable the `IP` plus the digits from the `range()`.

Comment: Glad to know I was close. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use a list to archive the values

```
ip = '192.168.1.'
ips = []
for i in range(70,91):
    ips.append(ip+str(i)
print(ips)
```

Answer (score 0):

IP = "192.168.1."

Iprange=""

for n in range(70,91):

```
Iprange += IP+str(n) + "\n"
```

print(Iprange)

Try this lines. You have to assign range to another variable instead of same IP variable